# how to trigger all module are loaded with requireJs

Tags: javascript, require

I am using requirejs to load javascript module.
Is there a way to trigger an event when all module are loaded?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [taken from the API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles), you can add a callback to the main `requirejs` function:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'], callMe); // the second parameter is the callback

function callMe($, canvas, sub) {
  console.log('everything is loaded');
   // the libraries are now available as parameters in the same sequence as in the array
  console.log('loaded', $, canvas, sub);
}
```